# How to disable button in KO JS after some event happens?

Tags: javascript, razor, knockout.js

I'm trying to enable disabled button after I load a table on the page.

```
self.uploadPdfButtonIsEnabled = false;
self.pricingTableRenderedHandler = function (data, stateName) {
        self.uploadPdfButtonIsEnabled = true;

        //some other irrelevant logic
}
```

.cshtml file

```
 <button class="button button--primary" id="uploadPdfsButton" data-bind="click: $root.openPdfUpload, enable: uploadPdfButtonIsEnabled">
      <span class="button__text">Upload PDF</span>
 </button>
```

As a result, I only get this button disabled and it is not enabled. Tried to debug and the **pricingTableRenderedHandler** is entered, **uploadPdfButtonIsEnabled** becomes true but the button is still disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an observable for the knockout binding to be able to update automatically:

```js
// Pass the initial value: `false`
self.uploadPdfButtonIsEnabled = ko.observable(false);
self.pricingTableRenderedHandler = function (data, stateName) {
  // Update by calling with the new value: `true`
  self.uploadPdfButtonIsEnabled(true);
}
```